# UPDATE mysql query using ip2nation IP values

Tags: mysql

I have a table in a database called tbl1 and in this I have IP addresses converted to the long number to allow me to compare them using ip2nations databse. For example I have

```
ip           | ip_number    |   country code
27.33.41.150 | 455158166    |
```

I have then downloaded the [ip2nation](http://www.ip2nation.com/ip2nation) database and added this to my database. Their example of converting the number to the country is this

```
SELECT country 
FROM ip2nation 
WHERE ip < 455158166
ORDER BY ip DESC 
LIMIT 0,1
```

ip2nation is the table that they have available on their website to download. It has 2 columns which are

```
ip         |  country
```

I want to be able to run an update query on all the values I have in my database (100k) to convert the ip_number I have to a country code (country column in the ip2nation table). How would I do this as I am not sure how to write the update query with the < identifier in their example query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you had database with range , for example ip_start , ip_end ,then you could just select country where ip is between these ip_start and ip_end , but for your example , you can update table this way

```
UPDATE your_table t
SET t.country_code =
   (SELECT i.country
      FROM ip2nation i
     WHERE i.ip < t.ip
     ORDER BY i.ip DESC LIMIT 0, 1)
```